Why symbolic access to x64 assembly function parameters stopped to work from MSVC2013
I needed to catch parameters of function written in x64 assembly. First 4 parameters are stored in registry. They are fine.
It seems that it was possible to use symbolic address as depicted in example. Starting from MSVC2013 Microsoft corrupted something and a symbolic access stopped to work.
It is possible to access stack directly
mov   ecx,[rsp+28h+4*8]
it seems to me to be a complete degradation of assembly.
Did I miss something?
;void YUV_RGB(unsigned char *OutData, const unsigned char *y, const unsigned char *u, const unsigned char *v, unsigned PixelCount)
    public YUV_RGB
    
IF @Version LT 1200
YUV_RGB proc \
        uses rdi rsi rbx,
        OutData: ptr BYTE,
        y: ptr BYTE,
        u: ptr BYTE,
    v: ptr BYTE,
    PixelCount: DWORD   ; on stack

ELSE
; The ASM from MSVC2013 seems to be much more worse than previous one.
YUV_RGB proc \
        uses rdi rsi rbx
ENDIF
    
    mov rdi,rcx     ; [OutData]
    mov rsi,rdx     ; [y]
IF @Version LT 1200
    mov ecx,PixelCount
ELSE
    mov ecx,[rsp+28h+4*8]   ;28h stays for 5th arg; rbp,rdi,rsi,rbx are now on the stack
ENDIF
.....................
    ret
YUV_RGB endp

I try to read Microsoft ml64 documentation, but it seems to be pretty useless. It does not describe functionality of proc macro well.
Similar topic has been solved here: Retrieve arguments of a x64 masm assembly procedure
But there is not solved easy symbolic access to function parameters above 4.
I have workable solution for now but is still sems to me that I overlook something how to handle arguments. This works fine for dozens of years in x86 assembly.
PS:
Z:\prog\latex\sources.cc\images>ml64 /c /nologo /W3 img_tool_MSVC64.asm
 Assembling: img_tool_MSVC64.asm
img_tool_MSVC64.asm(695) : error A2071:initializer magnitude too large for specified size
img_tool_MSVC64.asm(695) : warning A6004:procedure argument or local not referenced : OutDataimg_tool_MSVC64.asm(695) : warning A6004:procedure argument or local not reference
img_tool_MSVC64.asm(695) : warning A6004:procedure argument or local not reference
img_tool_MSVC64.asm(695) : warning A6004:procedure argument or local not reference
img_tool_MSVC64.asm(695) : warning A6004:procedure argument or local not reference

/W3 causes an artifical error. Without /W3 code gets compilled without any problem.
Z:\prog\latex\sources.cc\images>ml64 /c /nologo img_tool_MSVC64.asm
 Assembling: img_tool_MSVC64.asm

Z:\prog\latex\sources.cc\images>

Older ml64 compiles this fine even with /W3
Z:\prog\latex\sources.cc\images>ml64 /c /nologo /W3 img_tool_MSVC64.asm
 Assembling: img_tool_MSVC64.asm
img_tool_MSVC64.asm(695) : warning A6004:procedure argument or local not referenced : OutData
img_tool_MSVC64.asm(695) : warning A6004:procedure argument or local not referenced : y
img_tool_MSVC64.asm(695) : warning A6004:procedure argument or local not referenced : u
img_tool_MSVC64.asm(695) : warning A6004:procedure argument or local not referenced : v


How does it not work? What error do you get?

I am completelly puzzled for now. I have placed error output to the original message - here I am allowed to post 550 characters only. It seems that /W3 causes error to be generated, but without /W3 code gets compilled fine.
